# Is it possible a remote active directory authentication from local without VPN

Tags: active-directory

Can we authenticate to a remotely hosted DC from local machines without VPN connection to the server.
Server have Public IP & Local machines are using NAT. Currently there is no any other connection except Internet for access the server like VPN. So kindly give me an advice for this scenario and how to authenticate to Remote DC without VPN?? Or which is the right way to authenticate remote DC and how to do it?? Thanks in advance

Comment: `Can we authenticate to a remotely hosted DC from local machines without VPN connection to the server` - Yes, but you don't want to. `Currently there is no any other connection except Internet for access the server like VPN` - Then you can in fact create a VPN connection to the server. `which is the right way to authenticate remote DC and how to do it` - By creating a VPN connection.

Answer (score 5):

Using a VPN to access the remote Domain Controller (DC) computer is, arguably, the Right Way<sup>TM</sup> to be accessing it. Presumably the VPN terminates behind some type of firewall that is preventing the DC from being accessed directly over the Internet. All versions of Active Directory (AD), up to this point, are not recommended to be deployed with DCs in an Internet-facing configuration. AD wasn't designed with an Internet threat-model in mind.

It's unclear from your question if you're using a software VPN client on each client computer, or a hardware VPN client connected to the network. You'll have a better experience, in my opinion, using a hardware VPN client such that the local computers are able to access the DC during boot, prior to starting any VPN client software. I find that using a software VPN client is more cumbersome and creates additional failure modes.

You might look into Microsoft's DirectAccess VPN for this application, too. It would make the hosting network for the DC a bit more complicated but it might give you a more "transparent" VPN experience. (You will need "Enterprise" versions of your client operating systems, as well).